# Update notification's text in Android (depending on previous value)

Tags: android, notifications

I'm implementing an application that receives messages and notifies you when you receive them. I want to implement a notification system similar to Whatsapp: if I receive only one message, the title of the message will be shown in the notification; if then I receive antoher one, the notification has to say I have two messages, and so on.

I wanted to get the previous contentText of the notification to be able to know how many messages has the user received until now and then add to it the number of messages received now, but I can't find how to get it.

I found this in android-developers: "You can revise each property with the object member fields (except for the Context and the notification title and text)." Does this mean I can't get the contentText? If I can't get it, should I save the number in a static class or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can not get the contentText of a notification. Check out my answer, it's a workaround to solve that kind of problem. Hopefully Android will provide an easier way soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late answering your question, but here is how you could integrate it with kind of a workaround:

(1) Within your application you need a variable which counts the 'unread messages'. I would recommend you to integrate a class which extends `android.app.Application`. This helps you to handle variables globally, e.g. in multiple Activities. Here is an example:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class DataModelApplication extends Application {

    // model
    private static int numUnreadMessages;
    // you could place more global data here, e.g. a List which contains all the messages

    public int getNumUnreadMessages() {
        return numUnreadMessages;
    }

    public void setNumUnreadMessages(int numUnreadMessages) {
        this.numUnreadMessages = numUnreadMessages;
    }

    ...
}
```

Do not forget to add the application to your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="name.of.your.package.DataModelApplication" >

    <activity ... />
    ...
</application>
```

(2) In your `Activity` or `Fragment` you increment the `numUnreadMessages` by using the the setter everytime you receive a new message, e.g.:

```
// within a Fragment you need to call activity.getApplication()
DataModelApplication application = (DataModelApplication) getApplication();
int numUnreadMessages = application.getNumUnreadMessages();
application.setNumUnreadMessages(++numUnreadMessages);
```

(3) Now you can update your Notification with the number of unread messages, e.g.

```
// within your service or method where you create your notification
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, 0);

DataModelApplication application = (DataModelApplication) getApplication();
int numMessages = application.getNumUnreadMessages();

// build the notification
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
String contentTitle = "You have " + numMessages + " unread message(s)";
String contentText = "Click here to read messages";

Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
    .setContentText(contentText)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setNumber(numMessages) // optional you could display the number of messages this way
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

notificationManager.notify(notifyID, notifyBuilder.build());
```

(4) Don't forget to reset or decrement the value of numUnreadMessages everytime the user reads a message or if the user opens the Activity by clicking on that Notification. It's similar to step (2) but decrementing the value or set it to `0`.

Hope that helps you/anybody getting started :)

Comment: Hi! I ended up implementing a solution similar to yours to solve it, but I forgot to post it here afterwards. Anyway, I accepted your answer, I hope it helps all the people with the same problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **notify** method with the same notification id used for the old notification

> public void notify (String tag, int id, Notification notification)
>   Since: API Level 5
>   Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same tag and id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Comment: Yeah, I already knew that, but as I say my problem is that I want to GET previous contentText before replacing the notification. Thank you anyway ^^